# how to display table records who has one record when another table who is joined has many records

Tags: php, mysql

this site is like an ecommerce site and i have two tables that i'm stuck on.

```
tbl_products
---------------
phash
product
price
desc
maxcount


tbl_product_images
-------------------
phash
thumb
large
```

tbl_products stores the products description 
tbl_product_images stores the path of the thumb and large image of eac product.

phash is an md5 of the products name its what i use rather than the id or product name when matching things together.

what i'm having throuble with is say tbl_products has one record for a product and tbl_product_images
in relation to that product has 5 rows for its images.

how would i run the query?

```
$sql = "select
    tbl_products.phash
    tbl_products.product
    tbl_products.price
    tbl_products.desc
    tbl_products.maxcount
    tbl_product_images.phash
    tbl_product_images.thumb
    tbl_product_images.large
    from tbl_products
    inner join tbl_product_images
    on tbl_products.phash = tbl_products_images.phash";
```

this will display 5 rows of records since tbl_product_images has 5 records.

the way i output is my traditional way

```
$query = $db->query("$sql");
while($row = $db->fetch($query))
{
....

}
```

i am really unsure how i'm going to do this, if you need more explanation to what i'm trying to explain please let me know. thanks

Comment: What do you expect for output?  You're getting duplicates from TBL_PRODUCT_IMAGES

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way is to limit the number of results coming from the images table - though that's only appropriate if you don't care which image is returned for each product:

```
select
    tbl_products.phash
    tbl_products.product
    tbl_products.price
    tbl_products.desc
    tbl_products.maxcount
    tbl_product_images.phash
    tbl_product_images.thumb
    tbl_product_images.large
    from tbl_products
    inner join (SELECT * FROM tbl_product_images LIMIT 1) images
    on tbl_products.phash = images.phash
```

You can add an ORDER BY [col] DESC to that LIMITed query if there's some other column in the images table (like a date) you could use to determine which image appears.

(Note: If there **were** some column in tbl_product_images that determined which image to return, you could either put that in a `WHERE` clause on the query, or include it in the join criteria, like: `ON tbl_products.phash = tbl_product_images.phash AND tbl_product_images.color = 'Blue'`)

Further, if you *are* trying to get a product with all of its images, but only want one row in the resultset, it may be possible to "pivot" the set of images into columns. However, this is tricky if you can have an arbitrary (or simply large) number of images per product. You may be better off just returning multiple rows per product, and handling the results in your application code...

Comment: Also, just out of curiosity: why are you using an MD5 hash as a foreign key instead of a product's ID?

Comment: stay tuned dj i'll explain to you. i have to drop off someone. its much better to do the hash rather than the id in my opinion ull see.

Comment: ok, i wrote a small sample dont know if this sample will help but i'll try. http://i51.tinypic.com/w2lmb4.jpg you can see i have two products and each product has many images. these images are uploaded by a client on the backend. each time their added an md5 hash is stored as the id generated from the products name. you might ask why not just relate the product and the image with the product name. well the thing is that if the file name has many many characters with spaces and

Comment: symbols in it then either errors might occur or it woudl be bad pracitce. i use md5 or sometimes sha1 or whatever else to keep things short and that i can relate a product to its images. if i used id in the products table and add the id for the product in the images table it can work but i dont know. but do you get me?

Comment: @SarmenHB I do get you, yes. But allow me to suggest that an integer ID column from the products table would be an even-shorter foreign key, and is widely accepted as standard practice. Depending on how you're storing the hash (I assume as a character string of some kind?), it may have a significant impact on JOIN performance as well. So please reconsider "but I don't know". :)

Comment: I would use a surrogate key.  What happens when you correct a misspelled Product Name?  Would some image records now become orphans because the hash has changed? I can't see your tinypic.com url at work.  It is being blocked by our websense filter :(

Comment: @jeff Brings up an even more compelling reason not to use hashes of the product name! :) Though I presume that the OP would only hash the name on insert and maintain the hash as the surrogate key - if the hash were updated alongside the name (or computed from it), yes... that would make the DB very easy to break.